# Why exactly is dlopen not usable from a statically linked library?

Tags: unix

This [this Python Enhancement Proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/#key-causes-of-inter-linux-binary-incompatibility) states that:

> While it is possible, statically linking glibc is usually a bad idea
> because certain important C functions like dlopen() cannot be called
> from code that statically links glibc.

I don't have experience about how dynamically/statically linked library work internally, so I don't understand why you can't refer to a symbol dynamically from a static library?

Comment: Is your question a duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476533/why-is-statically-linking-glibc-discouraged