# How to link libc statically with CMake?

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake, static-libraries

How can I link libc (or glibc) statically with CMake on Linux?

I have already linked libgcc and libstdc++ by using -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++".

Comment: You don't want to do this, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476533/why-is-statically-linking-glibc-discouraged).

Comment: Is it using those flags as you expect?